# Mysql, Failure to Create Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, triggers

The columns are just int(10). The foreign table column is primary key. Why this error?

Referencing Table:

```
mysql> describe civicrm_entity_financial_account;
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| entity_table         | varchar(64)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| entity_id            | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| account_relationship | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| financial_account_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Referenced Table:

```
mysql> describe civicrm_financial_account;
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name            | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| account_type_id | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

SQL command:

```
ALTER TABLE `civicrm_entity_financial_account`  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_civicrm_entity_financial_account_financial_account_id` FOREIGN KEY (`financial_account_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_financial_account` (`id`);


ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you want to make sure your tables' engine is `InnoDB`, not `MyISAM`, since latter doesn't support foreign key. If that's the case, you can change engine:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

If this is not the issue, you can check for specific error by running:

```
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G
```

and then looking in `LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR` section.

Good luck!

Comment: I couldn't get indexes to make any difference. The doc referenced above says that an index will be created implicitly.

Comment: Looks promising  FOREIGN KEY (`financial_account_id`) REFERENCES `civicrm_financial_account` (`id`):
Cannot resolve table name close to:
 (`id`)
---------

Comment: Looks like the tables are myisam - which we haven't used in a while.

Comment: The fix was to change all the files to InnoDB mysqldump | sed 's#MyISAM#innodb#g' | mysql -u ... Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Interlated: Great! Actually, you can change table engine easier: `ALTER TABLE table_name ENGINE = InnoDB;`